# Preloader keep loading without showing the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made this site with HTML and Js, CSS but the preloader works fine in offline but when i put it on server it keep loading without showing the actual page. Please i need help

```js
//Preloader
var $preload = $('#preloader') ,
$loader = $('#loader');
if $preload.length > 0) {
console.log("load")
$win.on('load', function() {
$loader. fadeOut(300);
$body_m.addClass("loaded");
$preload.delay(700).fadeout(300);
});
}
```

```html
<div id="preloader">
<div class="loading">-- Projecton Loading --</div>
<div id="loader">
</div>
<div class="loader-section loader-top"></div>
<div class="loader-section loader-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your browser dev tools show? has the image finished loading?

Comment: Please look at the webpage, Projecton.pro

Answer (score 1):

You if statement is throwing error;
change this

```
if $preload.length > 0) {
```

to this

```
 if ($preload.length > 0) {
```

Comment: Okay thanks, can you look at the page ? Projecton.pro

Comment: You need to provide a link to the page.

Comment: i tired but its not opening.

Comment: I mean the website is not opening, it is giving me connection timed out error.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be relying on `window.load` events. They can trigger at different times in certain browsers and could have already triggered before your script has had a chance to start running.

You're already using jQuery which has its own `ready` event that fires when the DOM has loaded.

```
$(function() {
  $('#loader').fadeOut(300)
  $body_m.addClass("loaded")
  $('#preloader').delay(700).fadeout(300)
})
```

By putting all your selectors (eg: `$('#loader')`) inside this ready function, you can ensure they all exist.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Preloader
var $preload = $('#preloader') ,

$loader = $('#loader'); 


// Syntax error => missing "("
// if $preload.length > 0) {

// Correct Line
if ($preload.length > 0) { 
    console.log("load")

    // What is $win here?
    // Maybe you meant $(document) 
    $win.on('load', function() {

        $loader.fadeOut(300);

        // Again, what is $body_m ?
        $body_m.addClass("loaded");

        $preload.delay(700).fadeout(300);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloader">
<div class="loading">-- Projecton Loading --</div>
<div id="loader">
</div>
<div class="loader-section loader-top"></div>
<div class="loader-section loader-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay thanks but can you look at the site ? Projecton.pro